# Using upgraded AngularJS compoenent in Angular, giving Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider while testing

Tags: angularjs, angular-components, ng-upgrade, testbed

I have upgraded a AngularJS Component 'contactBox' into 'contactBoxDirective' and used in the angular component 'personInfo'.

But, while running the test cases using the TestBed, I am always getting the error

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: contactBoxDirectiveProvider <- contactBoxDirective
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.9/$injector/unpr?p0=contactBoxDirectiveProvider%20%3C-%20contactBoxDirective
>       at C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/3ac750590575e0af0efa9c7ea3a7a188.browserify:160495:12
>       at C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/3ac750590575e0af0efa9c7ea3a7a188.browserify:165266:19
>       at Object.getService [as get] (C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/3ac750590575e0af0efa9c7ea3a7a188.browserify:165426:32)
>       at C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/3ac750590575e0af0efa9c7ea3a7a188.browserify:165271:45
>       at Object.getService [as get] (C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/3ac750590575e0af0efa9c7ea3a7a188.browserify:165426:32)
>       at Function.UpgradeHelper.getDirective (C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/3ac750590575e0af0efa9c7ea3a7a188.browserify:116067:36)
>       at new UpgradeHelper (C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/3ac750590575e0af0efa9c7ea3a7a188.browserify:116064:53)
>       at contactBoxDirective.UpgradeComponent (C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/3ac750590575e0af0efa9c7ea3a7a188.browserify:116364:23)
>       at new contactBoxDirective (C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/3ac750590575e0af0efa9c7ea3a7a188.browserify:3360:23)
>       at createClass (C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/3ac750590575e0af0efa9c7ea3a7a188.browserify:93137:20)
>        Expected undefined to be truthy.
>       at UserContext. (C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/3ac750590575e0af0efa9c7ea3a7a188.browserify:2400:27)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invoke (C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/3ac750590575e0af0efa9c7ea3a7a188.browserify:246922:26)
>       at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/3ac750590575e0af0efa9c7ea3a7a188.browserify:246437:39)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invoke (C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/3ac750590575e0af0efa9c7ea3a7a188.browserify:246921:32)

Test Code -

```
describe('PersonModalContentComponent', () => {
  let $injector: angular.auto.IInjectorService;
  let component: PersonModalContentComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<PersonModalContentComponent>;


  beforeAll(() => {
    // First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
    getTestBed().resetTestEnvironment();
    getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
        BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
        platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
    );
  });

  beforeEach(angular.mock.inject((_$injector_: ng.auto.IInjectorService) => {
    $injector = _$injector_;
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [ {
        provide: '$injector',
        useFactory: () => $injector,
        deps: []
      }, NgbModal, NgbActiveModal ],
      imports: [
        TestsModule,
        NgbModule.forRoot(),
        TranslateModule.forRoot(),
        PersonDetailsModule
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });


  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PersonModalContentComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });


  it('should create PersonModalContentComponent', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

});
```

Comment: This only happens when testing? Accessing the app normally does not cause this error?

Comment: No, this was happening only when testing. finally i figured it out by using the `schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]`  to avoid loading of sub-components and it started working. I am just not sure, if this is the right approach